# how to integrate firebase to reactnative

Tags: react-native

I am try to integrate firebase to react-native
I tried this

```
npm install firebase --save
```

[image: getting error message]

Comment: try removing `node_modules` folder and then reinstall it again: `npm install`

Comment: yup its working thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native manages dependencies through npm. To install Firebase, run the following command .

`npm install firebase --save`.

if its not working then deleted node_modules . then install npm .then run npm install firebase --save.

add the following line to the top:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Then right above the component, initialize Firebase with your config values:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<your-api-key>",
  authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
  databaseURL: "<your-database-url>",
  storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",,
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

get more information from [HERE](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html)